# Repetitive MIDI FF 51 03 events?

Tags: midi

If I'm not mistaken, The meta-event `51 03` is for setting the tempo of the song. In this [midi file](http://games4um.ga.funpic.de/The%20Black%20Pearl.mid) that I've been studying (to learn the midi protocol), I've noticed that it calls this event over and over again. Is there a reason for this, or maybe it's just a glitch from the DAW?

[image: FF 51 03]

Comment: That event should only be issued when the new tempo is different. Repetitive Tempo Change events may be issued by DAWs due to a feature which is commonly used for DJs. Normal MIDI keyboards do not generate this event repetitively.

Comment: This is likely some sort of automatic tempo detection that is having a difficult time figuring out the tempo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file just has a bunch of tempo changes. That is perfectly valid. I opened it in Logic and here is what the Tempo List window looks like:

[image: Tempo List]

Here's a graphic view:

[image: Tempo Track]

It's a little weird that it has three different tempos at the very beginning of the song, but it's a valid MIDI file.